# Python: select a line if specific characters spaced by tab at end of line

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find out how to best select specific lines from multiple txt files in Python. One way could be to use regex, but I have read that this would probably be a 'heavy' solution for a simpler selection process of lines. Another possibility may be string.split() but it seems that I would have to split all lines first before making my selection. The selection I intend to make is upon the following condition:

if a line end with 'a tab a tab' then I select that line

in regex this would be the following:

```
((a\t){2}|(b\t){2})\n # character 'a' or 'b' at end of line
```

The function line.endswith('a   a   ') is also available, yet this does not recognize tabs.

```
if line.endswith('a a   '): # tabs are not recognized at end of line
```

Can you please advice if regex is a good or too heavy use or if string.split or another function like line.endswith is more appropriate?
Thank you.

Comment: A tab in a string is not four spaces, *it's a tab* `'\t'`; `line.endswith('a\ta\t')` (Star Wars reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endswith` is enough to solve your selection problem:

`\t` is a nice way to represent a `tab` in a python string:

```
>>> print('a\ta\t')
a       a
```

And `endswith` match it nicely:

```
>>> print('foobar a\ta\t'.endswith('a\ta\t'))
True
```